# Why do I need to handle an exception for Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

To get this code to compile, I can either:

- Put my call to [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) in a try/catch block, or
- Have `printAll()` declare that it can throw an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Why do I have to do this?

```
class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
          printAll( args );
    }

    public static void printAll( String[] line ) {
        System.out.println( lines[ i ] );
        Thread.currentThread().sleep( 1000 ):
    }
}
```

(Sample code from [Kathy Sierra's SCJP book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060).)

I know that the exception which `Thread.sleep()` throws is a checked exception, so I have to handle it, but in what situation does `Thread.sleep()` need to throw this exception?

Comment: Because Sleep method has checked exception ...

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I know this checked exception, But why in which situation we need to handle exception?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If a method is declared in a way that it can throw checked exceptions (`Exception`s that are not subclasses of `RuntimeException`), the code that calls it must call it in a `try-catch` block or the caller method must declare to throw it.

[`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is declared like this:

```
public static void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
```

It may throw [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) which directly extends [`java.lang.Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) so you have to catch it or declare to throw it.

And why is `Thread.sleep()` declared this way? Because if a [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is sleeping, the thread may be interrupted e.g. with [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) by another thread in which case the sleeping thread (the `sleep()` method) will throw an instance of this `InterruptedException`.

**Example:**

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Done sleeping, no interrupt.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I was interrupted!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
t.start();     // Start another thread: t
t.interrupt(); // Main thread interrupts t, so the Thread.sleep() call
               // inside t's run() method will throw an InterruptedException!
```

**Output:**

```
Sleeping...
I was interrupted!
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: @UnKnown On the contrary, we shouldn't interrupt a thread. A common technique is to signal the thread that it should end its running, and the thread itself should monitor whether such request was made (and if so, terminate gracefully by returning from the `run()` method).

Comment: Having the possibility of an exception from Thread.sleep is, IMO, terrible API design

Answer (score 7):

One `Thread` can communicate with and interact with another `Thread`, and one way that it can do it is by interrupting it: if `t` is another `Thread`, you can call `t.interrupt()` to ask it politely to stop what it's currently doing. This is in particular something you might want to do if `t` is sleeping: you might want to wake it up. What it does is to cause an `InterruptedException` in `t`'s `Thread.sleep()` method, so that it can catch it and respond. Because of this, any time you use `Thread.sleep()` to make the current thread go to sleep, you have to deal with the possibility of an `InterruptedException` in case another thread decides to wake it up.

In your case, you've only got one `Thread`, so you know that there can't be an `InterruptedException` from elsewhere in your code. But it's a not uncommon thing to want to do in multi-threaded code.

Answer (score -2):

```
 class Demo extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        system.out.println("hello Ziyad");
        thread.sleep(1000);
    }} }
            public class Threddemo{
        public static void main(string[] args) throws interruptedexception {
            Demo t=new Demo();
            Demo t2=new Demo();
        t.start();
        t2.start();
            }}
```

Suppose We have two Thread t and t2 and t is executing while executing, t2 came and t2  is also start executing  but t is not finish yet
        there the thread get interrupted and you lose your data.In above example t thread is running and when in spleeping mode, and there t2 came
        and start executing suddenly t get up but t2 is running this is chance of interruptedexception and data lose to avoid this we use interruptedexception